# Change server token end point for ember simple auth devise add on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I have an ember-cli app that uses ember simple auth(ember-simple-auth-devise) add on for authentication. I need to change the token end point of my authorizer to

http://example.com/api/v1/users/sign_in.

In my environment.js file I have added

```
ENV['simple-auth'] = {
        authorizer: 'simple-auth-authorizer:devise',
        crossOriginWhitelist: ['http://example.com'] //For CORS
    };

ENV['simple-auth-devise'] = {
      serverTokenEndPoint : 'http://example.com/api/vi/users/sign_in'
    }
```

But on logging in its still posts the credentials to the default url i.e. 
http://example1.com/users/sign_in.

How can I change this url to use my rails app endpoint.

Comment: are you running version 0.6.7 of the Ember CLI Addon and ran the generator (`ember g ember-cli-simple-auth-devise`) after updating?

Comment: yes my version is 0.6.7 and i ran the generator. every thing is working fine its redirecting to my login route on authenticated routes just my end point is not configuring as expected

Comment: What's your Ember CLI version? Please open an issue on github if you feel this is a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the problem is that the property key is `serverTokenEndpoint` with a **lowercase p**. If you go to [API docs](http://ember-simple-auth.simplabs.com/ember-simple-auth-oauth2-api-docs.html#SimpleAuth-Authenticators-OAuth2) you can see the correct property name.